# Externalizing HTML Templates in Backbone: Pros/Cons

Tags: backbone.js

What are the pros/cons of externalizing HTML templates in Backbone? Are there any best practices (ex. don't do it in production!).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the biggest advantage is that external templates can be used in javascript tests as fixtures. It also makes them modular so they can be used by more than 1 view. The only downside I can think of is that fact that an extra HTTP request has to made to download the template. However this could be solved using a proper build process for your AMD library.